# Why does Chrome get 200 response but Postman fail to get any response?

Tags: google-chrome, web-crawler

I want to crawl the content of the following page:

```
http://www.aae3.com/bt/cl/x7btc.php?download=down
```

When I use *Chrome* to open this page, I can see an empty file named *torrent* been downloaded.

If I use devtools in *Chrome* I can see the request returns 200.

[Chrome Devtools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5c9o.png)

And then, I tried to use *postman* to get this page, no matter how I fill in headers, *postman* always fail to get any response.

[Postman Get Request Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgQi2.png)

Why is there such difference? What should I do to get the same behavior with *Chrome* browser?

Answer (score 0):

Compare the Request Headers, maybe there is a difference another agent Setting which is handled different.

Comment: I don't think so, I have copied all the fields in request headers, and tried to modify request header in all different ways. If you can try yourself it would be great help!